# Including an array key in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

From Smarty Documentation:

```
{* include a multi $variable template - eg amber/links.view.tpl *}
{include file="$style_dir/$module.$view.tpl"}
```

But I want to an array key's value to include smarty that I created before in php. Accessing an array key's value is simple just like this: `$array.key` in Smarty. But what about when I want to access it in an include string?

```
{include file="$array.key"} is equals to "$array".key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I can handle with this:

```
{include "modules/{$array.key}.tpl" style="{$array.key}"}
```